# Dependent project not rebuilding when dependency is rebuilt

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have two projects in a solution, one is a static library and the other is a program. I have set the program to have the library as a dependency. After making a change to the library, when I ask to build the program, it does rebuild the library, but it does not rebuild the program with the updated library.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so actually, it was because the library was building into the solution directory, and the program was looking for the lib file in the library's project directory.